# Ler diversos arquivos .txt e remover informações duplicadas

Tags: php

Tenho diversos arquivos .txt com matrículas e algumas se repetem em arquivos diferentes e eu gostaria de remover todas as repetidas.

A primeira solução que pensei foi fazer uma comparação entre todos os arquivos usando PHP ou NodeJS, mas fiquei meio com o pé atrás e não sei se isso seria a melhor solução.

Depois pensei em jogar tudo num DB apenas para tratar, pq preciso dessas matrículas em arquivos .txt, mas vi que o DB iria ficar enorme, com muitas matrículas e talvez não seja muito viável por se tratar de centenas de arquivos e milhares de matrículas.

Qual seria a melhor solução para esse problema? Alguma dessas duas acima podem resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função **[file](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php)** para abrir o arquivo e jogar todo o conteúdo dele em um array.

Depois basta utilizar a função **[array_unique](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php)** para remover as linhas idênticas.

**01.txt**

```
valdeir
psr
naval
fuz. nav
valdeir
valdeir psr
stackoverflow
```

**Código PHP**

```
<?php

$files = glob("*.txt");

$content = [];

foreach($files as $file) {
    $content = array_merge($content, file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
}

$contentUniq = array_unique($content);

var_export($contentUniq);
```

**Output**

```
array (
  0 => 'valdeir',
  1 => 'psr',
  2 => 'naval',
  3 => 'fuz. nav',
  5 => 'valdeir psr',
  6 => 'stackoverflow',
)
```